# pyautogui перемещение курсора

Tags: python, pyautogui

Используя этот код мышка перемещается по указанным координатам
Если вместо координат пишу `pg.moveTo(cord, 3)` ничего не присходит

```
import pyautogui as pg

osk500  = 'osk500.PNG'
cord = pg.locateOnScreen(osk500, confidence = 0.7)
pg.sleep(1)
pg.moveTo(1101, 441, 3)
```

Comment: Уточните что именно вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Хочу сделать скрипт, который находит изображение на экране и переместит курсор на нее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pg.locateOnScreen(osk500, confidence = 0.7)` вернет кортеж, состоящий из 4ех элементов, для `pg.moveTo()` требуется только две координаты X и Y.

Вашим решением будет являться следующее:

```
import pyautogui as pg

osk500  = 'osk500.PNG'
cord = pg.locateOnScreen(osk500, confidence = 0.7)
pg.sleep(1)
pg.moveTo(pg.center(cord))
```

`pg.center()` вернет вам две координаты X и Y, по ним курсор и переместится